# how to retrieve an array in this OOP case? [php]

Tags: php, oop

While I know how to solve this in procedural `PHP`, I'm having difficulites with OOP. Some lines of code are shortened (e.g. html).

So, a user enters a number, which object $army1 passes to the constructor while creating itself. My constructor fills an array with for loop ($filled_army), but I don't know how to retrieve it the right way (so I could print it out after), since constructors don't have return values?
Adding `print_r($filled_army);` in constructor will print out the values, just to mention.

Also, if this problems shouldn't be solved through __construct, can someone help me how to do it through my own methods within class? I'm guessing it should be done with getters & setters, but I also had problems with using them, since one variable is passed in index.php, while other variable ($filled_army), is property of class...

**index.php**

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="size">
</form>

<?php
    $army1 = new Army($_GET['size']);
    // $army1->getArmy(); ??
?>
```

**army.class.php**

```
<?php
class Army {
  public $filled_army = [];
  public size;
  //...
  public function __construct($size){
        $this->size = $size;
        $arrayOfSoldiers = [10,20,30];

        for($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
        {
            $filled_army[$i] = $arrayOfSoldiers[mt_rand(0, count($arrayOfSoldiers) - 1)];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: could you explain the difference between prorcedural PHP and OOP?  is not clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have declared the `$filled_army` property as `public`, it will be available right after instantiating using standard object notation in PHP, for example:

```
$army1 = new Army($_GET['size']);
$army1->filled_army; // Now contains your array;
```

However, setting the property's visibility to `public` means that any code can modify the property, not only the object it was created by. Usually, to work around this we set properties to either `protected` or `private`, and then use getters/setters:

```
class Army
{
  private $filled_army = [];
  private $army_size   = 0;

  private static $_soldiers = [ 10, 20, 30 ];

  function __construct($size)
  {
    $this->army_size = $size;

    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
    {
      $this->filled_army[] = self::$_soldiers[ mt_rand(0, count(self::$_soldiers) - 1) ];
    }
  } 

  // Getter for the army:
  public function getArmy()
  {
    return $this->filled_army;
  }

  // Getter for the size:
  public function getArmySize()
  {
    return $this->army_size;
  }
}
```

Now, we can access the `getArmy()` method (or similarly the `getArmySize()` method):

```
$army1 = new Army($_GET['size']);
$army1->getArmy();     // Returns the army
$army1->getArmySize(); // Returns the value of $_GET['size'];
```

It's also worth noting that PHP supports [Magic Getters/Setters](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) which may be useful for your project.

Also note that we do not need a visibility modifier for the constructor function (`__construct()` in PHP is **always** publicly visible).

Comment: You forgot $this->filled_army in the constructor. The way it is currently written, getArmy will always return an empty array

Comment: @BenM First, I tried to edit your comment, missing `$i` and closing parentheses in the line where I fill an array.
Second, thanks for your code and explanations for everything.
I looked at your link few hours before your comment, but it seemed to me like this is a wrong situation for that.
About the given code, I tried it, and `$army->getArmy()` doesn't work. I have tried and tried, and still couldn't get it work. Do you have any ideas what could be the reason? I wrote everything as you did, with mentioned fixes, and can still only print out `$filled_army` through `for` loop in __construct.

Comment: @IvanLoler please see the edit, I forgot the `$this` assignment on the `filled_army` property, sorry! Also, the `$i` isn't required, since you're filling the array from its `0` index anyway (the array is always empty at the start).